# How do I remove/reset the Exception marking highlight in Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, highlighting

How do I remove the pink persistent exception marking highlight in Netbeans. This highlighting occurs when clicking a link in the exception stacktrace pointing to the project included offending code. Restarting the IDE doesn't help, and I'd rather not tinker in my user folders to delete files that may be useful for other purposes. Screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download a plugin and set it as desired (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46515/glsl-syntax-highlighter)